# Images not appearing in hostgator but appearing in localhost

Tags: javascript, php, html, html-table

I have a set of uploaded images in a members folder in a root directory.
When the page loads the images are not showing up.
When I inspect the element, I got a picture name and other parameters correctly but the picture doesn't show up.

[This is the output image i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvwB0.jpg)

[This is the result of inspect element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VywFZ.jpg)

I used the same code in localhost and it's working fine and all the images are loaded up. But now that I switched to hostgator it doesn't show the image.

```
<tr style="color:grey; font-size:15px;">
    <td width="1%"><? echo $headdata['USERID']; ?></td>
    <td width="1%"><img src="/members/<? echo $headdata['USERPIC']; ?>" width="150" height="150"  ></td>
    <td width="1%"><? echo $headdata['NAME'];?></td>
    <td width="1%"><? echo $headdata['AGE'];?></td>
    <td width="1%"><? echo $headdata['SEX'];?></td>
    <td width="1%"><? echo $headdata['MOBILE'];?></td>
    <td width="1%"><? echo $headdata['TYPE'];?></td>

    <?
        $txtreceived = $headdata['ID'];
        $IDS = encrypt_decrypt('encrypt', $txtreceived);
    ?>

    <td width="1%">
        <a href="editmemberdetails.php?UpdateId=<? echo $IDS; ?>" class="btn    btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        </a>
        <a href="editmember.php?UpdateId=<? echo $IDS; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Check your folder `path`

Comment: is it correct path ?

Comment: Try this `<td width="1%"><img src="http://www.your_domain.com/path/members/<? echo $headdata['USERPIC']; ?>" width="150" height="150"  ></td>`

Comment: don't use short tag <? echo $headdata['USERPIC']; ?>

Answer (score 0):

If your code in hostgator is not in root directory (www or public_html) and in your local host your code is in www root or public_html then your path of src not working on server because you have added `/` in `src="/members/..."`

so please check it with `src="./members/..."` still not working then check `members` folder permission in server it should be readable and writable `755` for apache user. and check file which is `$headdata['USERPIC'];` is exist in `members` folder?